# Oracle apex 5 - redirecting to page from a dynamic action

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a classic report where the last few columns are fa icons.

Using jQuerySelector i capture the "on click" event.

I do some calculations, and get back a number that I wanna pass to another page. I assign that number to a page item, that has an "on-change" event. Inside the event I have an "Execute JavaScript Code" containing the following:

```
var href = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:41:&SESSION.::::P41_ITEM:' +  $("#P40_ITEM").val();

window.location = href;
```

Now... the thing that bothers me the most with this, is that I already have code like this inside a dynamic tree, that's used for navigation, and it works as expected. But this get's bypassed all together. I encapsulated the "Execute JavaScript Code" with two "Execute PL/SQL Code" blocks with logs, and both of them recorded in the logs. Also, when i had "Fire on Page Load" set to yes the redirect happens.

I also tried something like this, thinking there's some mysterious reason it won't execute js code:

```
owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:10:&APP_SESSION.');

apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```

but this also doesn't work(can't even find if it's even suported in apex 5).

Does anyone know of a reason why this isn't working? Or another way to call a page redirect from a dynamic action?
tnx

Comment: Or if there's a way to fake a request, so i can submit and initiate a branch?

Comment: 1. Why not submitting the page when an icon is clicked? This'd be easier, no? 2. How do you set the value of the affected item which should get triggered? 3. When debugging, do you see the change event firing? (browser dev tools console!)

Answer (score 3):

You already answered your question with the comment

> Or if there's a way to fake a request, so i can submit and initiate a branch?

In dynamic action that listens to `change event` create `True` action `submit` after `Execute JavaScript Code`.

If you have trouble doing it, recreate the scenario on apex.oracle.com. Provide login credentials and I will check what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for not replying sooner. All your answers are probably correct, but i didn't get the chance to use them - as soon as i read my own highlighted text :) i figured what i was doing wrong. I put some of the logic in dynamic events and some of it in branch/process.. so yeah.. that didn't work.. fixed that up and all was well..

Comment: That is not an answer of the question.